# UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured

Tags: docker, kubernetes, udp, consul

We have a consul server cluster setup directly on VMs and we are now trying to setup consul clients on K8s running on different VMs. Consul agent is able to join the cluster but we have below issue. Netcat says it UDP port is open. Same ports are exposed in docker file, no additinal port-forward/expose is done at K8s level apart from the k8s podspec below.

```
    ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

2023-03-15T12:31:39.897Z [WARN]  agent: using enable-script-checks without ACLs and without allow_write_http_from is DANGEROUS, use enable-local-script-checks instead, see https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/protecting-consul-from-rce-risk-in-specific-configurations/
2023-03-15T12:31:39.903Z [WARN]  agent.auto_config: using enable-script-checks without ACLs and without allow_write_http_from is DANGEROUS, use enable-local-script-checks instead, see https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/protecting-consul-from-rce-risk-in-specific-configurations/
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: consul POD_IP
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent.router: Initializing LAN area manager
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=127.0.0.1:82210 network=udp
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=127.0.0.1:82210 network=tcp
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Starting server: address=127.0.0.1:82208 network=tcp protocol=http
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Started gRPC listeners: port_name=grpc address=127.0.0.1:82209 network=tcp
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [WARN]  agent.router.manager: No servers available
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No known Consul servers"
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: started state syncer
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Consul agent running!
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Retry join is supported for the following discovery methods: cluster=LAN discovery_methods="aliyun aws azure digitalocean gce hcp k8s linode mdns os packet scaleway softlayer tencentcloud triton vsphere"
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: Joining cluster...: cluster=LAN
2023-03-15T12:31:39.904Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=["consul_server_2", "consul_server_1", "consul_server_3"]
2023-03-15T12:31:39.907Z [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: hostA consul_server_2
2023-03-15T12:31:39.907Z [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: hostB consul_server_3
2023-03-15T12:31:39.907Z [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: hostC consul_server_1
2023-03-15T12:31:39.908Z [INFO]  agent.client: adding server: server="hostA (Addr: tcp/consul_server_2:82205) (DC: dc1)"
2023-03-15T12:31:39.908Z [INFO]  agent.client: adding server: server="hostB (Addr: tcp/consul_server_3:82205) (DC: dc1)"
2023-03-15T12:31:39.908Z [INFO]  agent.client: adding server: server="hostC (Addr: tcp/consul_server_1:82205) (DC: dc1)"
2023-03-15T12:31:39.910Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joined: number_of_nodes=3
2023-03-15T12:31:39.910Z [INFO]  agent: Join cluster completed. Synced with initial agents: cluster=LAN num_agents=3
2023-03-15T12:31:41.905Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostC over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:42.778Z [INFO]  agent: Synced node info
2023-03-15T12:31:42.905Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostB over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:43.905Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostA over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:44.906Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostA over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:45.906Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostC over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:46.906Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostB over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:47.907Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostC over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:48.908Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostA over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:49.909Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostB over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:50.910Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostA over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:51.910Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostB over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:52.911Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostC over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:53.911Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostB over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023-03-15T12:31:54.912Z [WARN]  agent.client.memberlist.lan: memberlist: Was able to connect to hostA over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
```

Our Podspec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: consul
spec:
  containers:
  - name: consul
    image: consul_test:0.4
    ports:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: consul
spec:
  containers:
  - name: consul
    image: consul_test:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: 82205
        hostPort: 82205
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82206
        hostPort: 82206
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82206
        hostPort: 82206
        protocol: UDP  
      - containerPort: 82207
        hostPort: 82207
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82207
        hostPort: 82207
        protocol: UDP
      - containerPort: 82208
        hostPort: 82208
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82209
        hostPort: 82209
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82210
        hostPort: 82210
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 82210
        hostPort: 82210
        protocol: UDP
```

Consul Agent config:

```
{
    "addresses": {
        "dns": "127.0.0.1",
        "grpc": "127.0.0.1",
        "http": "127.0.0.1",
        "https": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "advertise_addr": "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}",
    "advertise_addr_wan": "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}",
    "bind_addr": "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}",
    "client_addr": "127.0.0.1",
    "data_dir": "/var/lib/consul",
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "disable_update_check": true,
    "domain": "consul",
    "enable_local_script_checks": true,
    "enable_script_checks": true,
    "enable_syslog": false,
    "encrypt": "string",
    "encrypt_verify_incoming": true,
    "encrypt_verify_outgoing": true,
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "performance": {
        "leave_drain_time": "5s",
        "raft_multiplier": 1,
        "rpc_hold_timeout": "7s"
    },
    "ports": {

"dns": 82210,
"grpc": 82209,
"http": 82208,
"https": -1,
"grpc_tls": -1,
"serf_lan": 82206,
"serf_wan": 82207,
"server": 82205

    },
    "raft_protocol": 3,
    "retry_interval": "30s",
    "retry_join": [
        "server1",
        "server2",
        "server3"
    ],
    "retry_max": 0,
    "server": false,
    "syslog_facility": "local0",
    "translate_wan_addrs": false,
    "ui_config": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please look into the mentioned document and let us know if it is useful.
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/890/first-steps-consul-interpret-communication-errors-between-nodes

Comment: As per netcat ( nc -z -v -u ip port ) serf_lan port is open.

Comment: As per the above mentioned document, WAN gossip port also needs to be opened. If possible, please open "serf_wan" port.

Comment: it is open along with grpc too.